# Strange MySQL GROUP BY/ORDER BY behaviour

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

```
        SELECT
            p.price,
            h.name AS hotel_name
        FROM
            prices p
            LEFT JOIN hotels h ON p.hotel_id = h.id
        WHERE
            p.city = 'boedapest'
            AND p.hotel_id IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY p.name     
        ORDER BY p.price ASC
```

RESULT:
26  Eben Hotel Budapest
27  Veritas
28  Ibis Budapest Heroes Square
29  Hunguest Hotel Griff
30  Hotel Thomas
31  NH Budapest
31  Rubin Wellness and Conference Hotel
32  Benczur Hotel
33  Atlantic
33  Delibab Hotel Budapest

Exactly the same result with the GROUP BY commented out:
24  Gerand Hotel Ventura
25  Hunguest Hotel Platanus
26  Boulevard City Guesthouse
26  Tulip Inn Millennium Budapest
26  Eben Hotel Budapest
27  Veritas
27  Baross
28  Hotel Thomas
28  Hunguest Hotel Griff
28  Ibis Budapest Heroes Square

Basically I would like to GROUP by name, but keep the ORDER BY. Since 24 is less than 26, I kind of expect it to show up earlier than 26. Also keep in mind, I'm displaying only the first 10 results, to keep the post short.

I'm using: SELECT VERSION() -> 5.1.37

Comment: why are you using `GROUP BY` if you aren't using any aggregate functions?

Comment: So I can GROUP_CONCAT the prices. E.g.:

GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(transport, '||', price, '||', p.url) SEPARATOR '(|)') AS prices

For the sake of simplicity I omitted the GROUP_CONCAT.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `group by` on `p.name`, but selecting that field and another one ; and why are you using a `group by` here ? Is it really necessary ?

Quoting the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) page of the MySQL manual :

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY to
>   allow selecting fields that are not
>   mentioned in the GROUP BY clause. If
>   you are not getting the results that
>   you expect from your query, please
>   read the description of GROUP BY found
>   in Section [11.12, “Functions and
>   Modifiers for Use with GROUP BY
>   Clauses”.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html)

And reading [11.12.3. GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) might help :

> When using this feature, all rows in
>   each group should have the same values
>   for the columns that are ommitted from
>   the GROUP BY part. The server is free
>   to return any value from the group, so
>   the results are indeterminate unless
>   all values are the same.

Basically, adding an aggregate function on the `p.price` column somewhere might help, I'd say.

Comment: To be more precise. I'm GROUPING to add a GROUP_CONCAT and a LIMIT + OFFSET for pagination. For the sake of simplicity I removed the unnecessary code. But indeed, it's better to onderstand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `HAVING MIN(p.price)`.

Comment: Does not work. It changes a couple of rows but not in the beginning.

Comment: You question shows you grouping by p.name. Did you mean to group by h.name instead?

Comment: The names are equal. I know that it looks like poor design. But the names in the prices table were only used to grab the prices.

Comment: Humor me. One thing I've learned is that just because you *believe* two things are supposed to be equal does not mean that they actually *are*.

Comment: Thanks for recalling. You are right. I changed the GROUP BY so it GROUPS BY hotel_id. Unfortunately this does not change the result :(.

Answer (score 0):

Group By clause is mostly used when you need result with some aggregate functions like (sum, avg etc.)

another thing is you need to select column in your result set which you want to be group by.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else might struggle over this:

Add a `SELECT MIN(p.price) AS price` and then `ORDER BY price`. This will give you the desired result.